# Unused variable warning in XCode 6

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, mixpanel

I see this warning while compiling within the Mixpanel framework used in my project.

[image: Strange warning in XCode 6]

It was not showing when I compiled some moment back. Is it a bug in XCode 6? How the variable k is unused here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must be compiling with the constant `NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS` set, so those `NSAssert()` statements are disabled.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/#//apple_ref/c/macro/NSAssert):

> Assertions are disabled if the preprocessor macro `NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS`
>   is defined.

Comment: Thanks. I see it in the Custom Compiler Flags section in the Build Settings. It is there for the Release build, that's why I received warning while archiving. However, Is it important to keep it set?

Comment: Yeah I would keep it set, but add `#ifndef NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS` around that whole `if` statement.